# Why Does Excel Spontaneously Minimise Itself?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I use Excel all-day, every-day for my work. Occasionally when I click somewhere on a sheet, Excel spontaneously minimises itself to the task bar and I am left looking at some other program. It is not related to a change in focus; I may have been working on the same sheet for some time. If I re-maximise Excel, it works as normal, as though nothing happened.

The issue does not seem to be consistently reproducible; it occurs at random, maybe once or twice a day. It does not appear related to macros, as it happens in workbooks without macros. I am using Excel 2010 in Windows 10. Has anyone experienced this, or does anyone have a guess why this might happen?

Comment: Have you ruled out the possibility that it's a Windows related issue? (Perhaps you're hitting some shortcut that's minimizing the window?)  Just asking because I've not seen that issue with Excel before.  Does it happen to any other Office programs?

Comment: Thanks Bruce, but it seems to just happen to Excel.